# PHP regex, skip <link> tags when rel="canonical"

Tags: php, regex

I run a PHP script in WordPress that removes the `http:` and `https:` protocols from all the links using the following regex:

```
$links = preg_replace( '/<input\b[^<]*\bvalue=[\"\']https?:\/\/(*SKIP)(*F)|https?:\/\//', '//', $links );
```

For the first part: `<input\b[^<]*\bvalue=[\"\']https?:\/\/(*SKIP)(*F)`, this skips any `<input>` tags that have a `http:` / `https:` value, such as:

```
<input type="url" value="http://example.com">
```

Additionally, I'd like it to skip any `<link>` tags that have a `rel="canonical"` attribute:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/remove-http/" />
```

Using a [regex tester](http://www.phpliveregex.com/), I've been trying to update the logic. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
<(input|link)\b[^<]*\(value|rel)=[\"\'](https?:\/\/|canonical)(*SKIP)(*F)|https?:\/\/
```

But this hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Not an answer, but you really should stop using protocol-relative URLs as they are bad for security and performance: [The Protocol-relative URL](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) and [Stop Using the Protocol-relative URL](https://jeremywagner.me/blog/stop-using-the-protocol-relative-url).

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/1PF7hB/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs are used to discard the text matched so far and proceed to search for the next match from the position where the regex index was after matching the text with the pattern before these verbs.

So, to match `word1` *or* `word2`, drop them and go on to look for `word3`, you need to use

```
'~(?:word1|word2)(*SKIP)(*F)|word3~'
```

The `(?:...)` non-capturing group will group the alternatives that must be dropped.

In your case, the whole `<link...>` should be matched, not just up to the attribute. Thus, you need something like `link\b[^>]*?\brel=[\'\"]canonical[\'\"][^>]*>` instead of `word2` in the above regex.

**However**, you should think about using an HTML parser that is compatible with your environment (I saw your note that the DOMDocument malfunctions there).

Comment: You're right, I switched to `DOMDocument`, but it was causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the built in PHP DOM class.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

HTML is a very rich language and regex are not powerful enough to parse it efficiently. Please never parse HTML using regex.

Parsing HTML using regex will drive SO users insane this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5909136

Comment: I did with the help of someone else for SO, [see this previous commit](https://github.com/factmaven/remove-http/blob/47ea5e81ea561ce3180336ca0dfd2c74d866d14f/remove-http.php) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41680789/6579923). But it was causing more issues, particularly in WordPress' admin panel. You're more than welcome to help improve that version before I reverted back to regex.