# Regex search Telefon but skip urls

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have a regex that works perfectly with the numbers I want to get, but the problem is with the URLs that also get them, how could I do to remove them?

Skip if there is no blank space, line break or the like?

Thanks !!

my current regex is:

> /((?(0{1,2}|+)\d{1,2})?)?(([ -]*\d+){8,20})+/gm

https://regex101.com/r/yzAScj/1

the modification I made doesn't work:

> /\s{1}((?(0{1,2}|+)\d{1,2})?)?(([ -]*\d+){8,20})+\s{0,1}/gm

https://regex101.com/r/yzAScj/2

Test text:

```
https://asd.com/20441235534-aaaaaaaaaaa-

202460676

aasdasd 202460676

https://asd.com/20441235534


202460676-



10 text
1234 text
text 123

00491234567890
+491234567890

0123-4567890

0123 4567 789
0123 456 7890
0123 45 67 789

+490123 4567 789
+490123 456 7890
+49 123 45 67 789

123 4567 789
123 456 7890
123 45 67 789


+49 1234567890
+491234567890

0049 1234567890
0049 1234 567 890

(0049)1234567890
(+49)1234567890

(0049) 1234567890
(+49) 1234567890



text text (0049) 1234567890 text text
text text (+49) 1234567890 text text
```

---

makes the phone numbers have the link "tel:" to be able to click on them.

You shouldn't pick a URL as a phone.

JS code (with jquery):

function searchAndReplacePhones(){

```
    var regex =  /(\(?(0{1,2}|\+)\d{1,2}\)?)?(([ -]*\d+){8,20})+/gm;

    //Beschreibung
    $(".my_text").html($(".my_text").html().replace(regex, " <a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a> "));

}
```

Comment: What is your regex flavor? The `regexp-replace` hints at Oracle, but you might have used it since you plan to use the regex in some replace method. Which one?

Comment: i use JS with Jquery replace

Comment: I also believe your original regex,`(\(?(0{1,2}|\+)\d{1,2}\)?)?(([ -]*\d+){8,20})+`, is off a bit, you want to match phone numbers that contain 8 to 20 digits, right? You quantified `\d` with `+`, and now you match 8 to 20 chunks of 1+ digits separated with space or hyphen, that might be too much.

Comment: What are you actually doing? Wrapping the numbers with some tag?

Comment: it makes the telephone numbers have the link "tel:" to be able to click them but it should not take a URL as a telephone.

I just edited the post. Thanks !

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61769376/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex that matches either a URL (say, with `https?://\S*`) or matches and *captures* the phone number:

```
var regex = /https?:\/\/\S*|((?:\(?(?:0{1,2}|\+)\d{1,2}\)?[ -]*)?\d(?:[ -]*\d){7,19})/gi;
```

Then, when you use it in the `.replace` method, you need to use a callback method, where you pass the regex match and analyze the structure of the match: if Group 1 matched, replace it, otherwise, put back the match value.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LxWTv/5) and a JS demo below:

```js
var text = "\n\nhttps://asd.com/20441235534-aaaaaaaaaaa-\n\n202460676\n\naasdasd 202460676\n\nhttps://asd.com/20441235534\n\n\n202460676-\n\n\n\n10 text\n1234 text\ntext 123\n\n00491234567890\n+491234567890\n\n0123-4567890\n\n0123 4567 789\n0123 456 7890\n0123 45 67 789\n\n+490123 4567 789\n+490123 456 7890\n+49 123 45 67 789\n\n123 4567 789\n123 456 7890\n123 45 67 789\n\n\n+49 1234567890\n+491234567890\n\n0049 1234567890\n0049 1234 567 890\n\n(0049)1234567890\n(+49)1234567890\n\n(0049) 1234567890\n(+49) 1234567890\n\n\n\ntext text (0049) 1234567890 text text\ntext text (+49) 1234567890 text text";
var regex = /https?:\/\/\S*|((?:\(?(?:0{1,2}|\+)\d{1,2}\)?[ -]*)?\d(?:[ -]*\d){7,19})/gi;
//https://regex101.com/r/0LxWTv/5
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + text.replace(regex, function($0,$1) {
  return $1 ? '<a href="tel:' + $1 + '">' + $1 + '</a>' : $0;
} ) + "</pre>";
```

Note I modified the pattern a bit:

- `(?:\(?(?:0{1,2}|\+)\d{1,2}\)?[ -]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\(?`
  - `(?:0{1,2}|\+)` - one or two zeros or `+`
  - `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
  - `\)?` - an optional `)`
  - `[ -]*` - 0 or more spaces or hyphens
- `\d`  - a digit
- `(?:[ -]*\d){7,19}` - seven to nineteen digits separated with 0 or more spaces or hyphens.

Comment: you're right, I was using my old code, it works great, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

[PHP regex, skip <link> tags when rel="canonical"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066317/php-regex-skip-link-tags-when-rel-canonical) shows the use of `(*SKIP)(*F)` trick, add `https?:\/\/\S*(*SKIP)(*F)|` to your expression:

```
https?:\/\/\S*(*SKIP)(*F)|(\(?(0{1,2}|\+)\d{1,2}\)?)?(([ -]*\d+){8,20})+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/yzAScj/3)

With `https?:\/\/\S*(*SKIP)(*F)|`, you skip URLs, match anywhere else.